# How to set the height of a MenuFlyout from c# in windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a `MenuFlyout` in the c#, I want to set the height of this flyout how can I do this as it doesn't contain a Height property.

Comment: Have you tried setting it in the xaml? I am not sure about windows 10 but think i have done it in windows 8 using a "Height" attribute

Comment: Otherwise you could try making the items within the flyout bigger and see if the size of the flyout automatically adjusts

Comment: Yeah the flyout will start having a scrollviewer after it has too many items but it looks awkward hence I would like to limit its height. Since I'm creating the flyout in c# I cant set it via xaml!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this in the C# code:

```
private void menuFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{         
    MenuFlyout m = sender as MenuFlyout;
    Style s = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Style { TargetType = typeof(MenuFlyoutPresenter) };
    s.Setters.Add(new Setter(MinHeightProperty, "800"));
    m.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle = s;
}
```

This would get the same effect as in following XAML code:

```
 <MenuFlyout Opened="menuFlyout_Opened">
       <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
           <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
              <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="800" />
           </Style>
        </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
  </MenuFlyout>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!